# div and p tag float is weird and not correct

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this url1:
http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-15/float.html
the text goes left to the float element.

But in this url2:
http://htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-15/columns-two.html
If I cancel the float property of the class "column2of2", the div doesn't stay besides the column1of2.

I just don't know why in the first url the text stays besides the floating div, but in the second url the class "column2of2"  cannot stay besides the floating div.

Comment: Remove 'float: left;' from the column2of2 div and add 'display: inline;' to that div

Comment: Both are floated block level elements followed by block level elements a <div> or a <p>. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

In the first url the quote is floated to right in **one element** body. Thats why the text wraps arround it.

In the second url the content is seperated from each other **with two divs** thats why the quote text doesnt surround the content.

Comment: I mean that in url one the content is wrapped in the body element, in the second one the content is wrapped in two divs

Comment: What is the "one element body"? Does this difference come from the mechanism difference between <div> and <p>? I just don't know the difference of the structure. Both are floated block level elements followed by block level elements a <div> or a <p>.

Answer (score 0):

**The display of content is perfectly correct in each of your examples.**

In the first example, the "correct" one. The text is displayed in the body of the page and another div is inside of the body, floating on the right of it. The content cannot be displayed in the region the floating div occupies because of it's display type which (by default) is `display: block;` see http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

In the second case, while text is still displayed in the body of the page you will observe that there are **two separate div's contained in the body of the page.** Because of their default display property, much like in the first, `display: block;` nothing can overlap.

---

---

See these two jsfiddles where I hilight the regions these things occupy:

.

"Correct" display: http://jsfiddle.net/vxVfg/

"Incorrect" display: http://jsfiddle.net/duTEt/1/

.

And here is the second one, the one which wasn't "correct" working:
.

"Incorrect" display - fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/duTEt/3/ *(if you are confused with the below explanation, I have left a good 3-4 line gap of what I edited in the HTML section of the jsfiddle, just open it and look)*

.

**This is what I changed:**

**The Rule**

```
.column2of2 
      {
        background: green;
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 10px;
      }
```

Became:

```
.column2of2 
      {
        background: green;
        float: right; /* THIS WAS CHANGED */
        width: 300px;
        margin: 10px;
      }
```

**Why? Well, we want it on the right side.**

---

**The position in the HTML Markup:**

Lastly, I took this:

```
            <div class="column2of2">
            <h3>Bicycle Timeline</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>1817: Draisienne</li>
                <li>1865: Velocipede</li>
                <li>1870: High-wheel bicycle</li>
                <li>1876: High-wheel safety</li>
                <li>1885: Hard-tired safety</li>
                <li>1888: Pneumatic safety</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And put it inside the containing div, as it should be, so it became:

```
<h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
        <div class="column1of2">

 /* I PUT IT HERE */

      <div class="column2of2">
            <h3>Bicycle Timeline</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>1817: Draisienne</li>
                <li>1865: Velocipede</li>
                <li>1870: High-wheel bicycle</li>
                <li>1876: High-wheel safety</li>
                <li>1885: Hard-tired safety</li>
                <li>1888: Pneumatic safety</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

 /* IT ENDS HERE */

            <h3>The First Bicycle</h3>
            <p>In 1817 Baron von Drais invented
```